# Batch file - Need to take input and append input (D or L) to each line of text to perform Ping on

Tags: batch-file, ping

I currently have this script to ping each network name in a file provided to me (1 per line) and output result and device name to a log file and it's working fine.

```
Set "ComputerList=C:\computers.txt"  ***currently have to run twice with D or L appended to ensure I identify all desktop or laptops
Set "LogFile=C:\PingResults.txt"

If Not Exist "%ComputerList%" Exit /B
>"%LogFile%" (For /F UseBackQ %%A In ("%ComputerList%"
) Do Ping -n 1 %%A|Find "TTL=">Nul&&(Echo Yes [%%A])||Echo No [%%A])
```

But now I would like to take input from a prompt to specify whether I'm searching for Desktops (D) or Laptops (L) and append that value to each entry in the %ComputerList% (in our environment all desktops names are D + service tag and laptops are L + service tag, e.g. D123abc, or L123abc), everything else should be the same.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

I am looking for advice on how to implement. I haven't attempted it myself yet.

Comment: Does your `computers.txt` file contain just the tags, or the tags with the prepended `D` or `L` ? Can a "tag" begin `D` or `L`? Are all of the "tag"s of the same length?

Comment: example computers.txt

gtm58c3
7v858c3
1qwbbc3

I do not know if these are desktops or laptops, so I currently use notepad++ to append a D, then run the script, then change the D to an L and run the script again.  I want to be able to append the D or L based on an input parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
Set "ComputerList=U:\q75523666.txt"
Set "LogFile=U:\PingResults.txt"
Set "TempFile=U:\Temporary.txt"

DEL "%tempfile%" 2>NUL

>"%LogFile%" (
FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%b IN (%computerlist%) DO (
 SET "group="
 IF "%%c"=="" (
  FOR %%t IN (D L) DO (
   PING -n 1 %%t%%b|Find "TTL=">NUL
   IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   Echo Yes [%%t%%b]
    >>"%tempfile%" ECHO %%b %%t
    SET "group=%%t"
   )
  )
  IF NOT DEFINED group (
   Echo No [?%%b]
   >>"%tempfile%" ECHO %%b
  )
 ) ELSE (
  PING -n 1 %%c%%b|Find "TTL=">Nul&&Echo Yes [%%c%%b]||Echo No [%%c%%b]
  >>"%tempfile%" ECHO %%b %%c
 )
)
rem ==== This is the beginning of a test routine for testing on MY system 
rem ==== where the PING would always fail.
FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%b IN (%computerlist%) DO (
 SET "group="
 IF "%%c"=="" (
  IF "%%b"=="7v858c3" (
   Echo Oui [X%%b]
   >>"%tempfile%" ECHO %%b X
   SET "group=X"
  )
  IF NOT DEFINED group (
   Echo Non [?%%b]
   >>"%tempfile%" ECHO %%b
  )
 ) ELSE (
  Echo Oui/Non [%%c%%b]
  >>"%tempfile%" ECHO %%b %%c
 )
)
rem ==== This is the END of a test routine for testing on MY system 
rem ==== Remove the code between the two "REM" blocks
)

MOVE "%tempfile%" "%computerlist%" >nul
```

### Notes

I've changed filenames to suit my system. I've included a test block that I used for debugging. This should be removed - it's there to show how I tested the routine since "ping" on your taglist will always fail on my system.

Read each line from the `computerlist` file. Use `for /f` (see `for/?` from the prompt or hundreds of examples on SO) to assign the tag to `%%b` and the group (D or L) to `%%c`

if "%%c" is empty, then we have not determined the group, so try the `ping...` with %%t=`D` or `L` prepended to the tag. If found, report "Yes" on the logfile and record "tag group" on the tempfile. If not, report "No" and record "group" only.

If `%%c` is not empty, test `%%c%%b`to produce the report and record "tag group" on the tempfile.

When `computerlist` has been fully processed, a new version will appear in `tempfile`, so move `tempfile` over `computerlist`.

### Caution

During your obligatory testing, it would be best to remark-out this `move` line (`rem move...`) and `type "%tempfile%"` to ensure that it contains the expected data which should be a list of tags with  `L` or  `D` appended if it has been determined that the tag belongs to a Laptop/Desktop OR the tag alone which indicates that it has not been determined whether the tag belongs to either group.

Comment: Thanks Magoo!  This worked great for my needs, and it's even better to not have to enter whether I'm searching for Desktops or Laptops.  Appreciate it very much!